# build apache from source forcing a debian configuration

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server

I've just built apache2 on a debian wheezy system from source (I had to do this because, try as I might, I couldn't get apache 2.2.22 and mod_perl 2.0.7-3 to play together on Wheezy. Apache keeps dying with a segfault whenever I start it, there exists a related bug report, but no fix that I've been able to find that works for me).

Anyway, the source install of apache and mod_perl has worked fine, however I notice that doing a make install with --enable-layout=Debian doesn't lay things out like the debian package. It doesn't include any sort of init.d start script and config file names are different (httpd.conf instead of apache2.conf for example). None of the debian config binaries are installed like a2enmod.  This seems odd, because in the apache2 source tree, there is a directory called "debian" and a lot of this stuff seems to be there.

I can't work out how I tell configure or make or whatever to install all the stuff in the debian directory and layout the install as it would if I installed the debian package with apt-get.

Any ideas?